# "Select All" does not work with twitter bootrap modal and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using for [bootstrap's modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

A very nice utility, but unfortunately "Select All" does not work for IE7/8/9, either from menu or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> keypress sequence.

Why? And how can I enable it? Or is it worth the trouble?

Comment: This addition to the bootstrap modal solves the problem. Don't know why, but going to go forward with this revision:
   https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how the **Modal** plugin enforces focus on the modal element.  You can disable the focus lock with the following snippet.

### JS

```
$('body').on('shown', '.modal', function () {
  $(document).off('focusin.modal')
})
```

<sub>**Note:** You can attach the listener to something other than the `<body>` element, especially if you don't need this behavior for all modals.</sub>

I've at least confirmed that running this will re-enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> in the older IE's.